# I want to use sumproduct with two different tables based on selection

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am working on a statistical model where we use sumproduct to generate forecast values by multiplying coefficients in one table with variables in another. Right now it is being done manually and that is taking time. I would like to automate it but I'm not able to figure this out.

We are using concatenate to identify different rows to use for vlookup. The variable columns are the same in number for both tables. I need to multiply each variable cell respectively in both tables and sum them, hence sumproduct.

this is what I am trying to do

Forecast model 1 sales for product A in phones in USA = sumproduct([variables by year from table 1 for USA for phones], [Variables for USA phone product A model 1 from table 2] )

I hope someone can help me.

[image: my sample file]

Comment: lol this is perfect `sumproduct` practice for me except I don't understand XD What variables are you multiplying?

Comment: @findwindow do you understand now???  Clear as mud?

Comment: @ForwardEd clear as mud, pure as driven snow.

Comment: @findwindow  Did my BRIEF explanation of the solution help with the purification?

Comment: @ForwardEd I don't want an explanation. I want to know what OP wants to do so I can try it myself. But yes, I am purified now.

Comment: @findwindow the OP wants to perform a sumproduct for a given row in table 1 for variables 1-3 with a given row in table 2 for variables 1-3.  That hard part was determining the row.  Once you know that you can do your sumproduct. So if you look at my image below which has column and row references, to get cell E21 to have a value of 34 in it, you are basically G3*F15+H3*G15+I3*H15.  In terms of sumproduct you are SUMPRODUCT(G3:I3,F15:H15).  This could have been done with offset, but that is a volatile function, so I learned my lesson from Scott Craner and used non volatile INDEX instead.

Comment: @ForwardEd aww you didn't have to. Busy :/ Will read when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

You will need to update the references to suit your spreadsheet table locations.

In cell E21 use the following and copy right and down as required:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($G$3:$I$12,MATCH($B21&$A21&$C21,$A$3:$A$12,0),0),INDEX($F$15:$H$18,MATCH($A21&$C21&$D21&MID(E$20,16,1),$A$15:$A$18,0),0))
```

This process was simplified because you had a unique ID tag on each of the previous two tables that could be built from the information in the third table.  If you ever get into double digit forecast models the MID() function part of the formula will need to be modified.  The 16 in the mid function refers to the character location of the number in the forecast model sales header name in Table 3.  As such you either need to keep that header format exactly the same or modify the position of the number in the MID() function.

### UPDATE 1

**Explanation of Formulas**

The following formulas were used in this solution:

- [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)
- [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
- [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
- [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)
- [Concatenate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)

I will start with the assumption that you already understand sumproduct() as you were already using it before you ran into your problem.  One thing to note about sumproduct is that it causes array like calculation to occur on the portion within it brackets.  In this case we fed it two ranges of equal size.  The difficult part was more an issue of determining those ranges.

Using your ID columns as a lookup row we used the match() function to determine which row to use.  For the first set of variables we used the following to determine which row to look in:

```
=MATCH($B21&$A21&$C21,$A$3:$A$12,0)
```

Match is made up of three arguments inside the brackets:

```
MATCH(what to look for, where to look, type of match)
```

What we need to look for in table is a concatenation of various cells in Table 3 to build the ID in Table 1.  It could have been written using the full formula:

```
=CONCATENATE($B21,$A21,$C21)
```

but the short form using & was used instead:

```
=$B21&$A21&$C21
```

Once we had what to look for we needed the range of where to look and supplied the ID column from table 1:

```
$A$3:$A$12
```

This now leaves the third and final argument of what type of search to perform.  An exact match seemed to be the most appropriate match to perform so the value of 0 was supplied.  What match returns is the row within the supplied range.  It is relative to the range supplied and not the actual row in the spreadsheet.  If it cannot make a match it will return an error instead of a row number.

Now that we know what row we want, we can use this information with the INDEX() function.  The INDEX() function is made up of 3 arguments as well with the third argument being optional depending on if a 1D or 2D range is being indexed:

```
INDEX(Range to work with, 2D Row or 1D Position reference, 2D Column reference)
```

IN the case we are dealing with for the first table, the range to work with was your list of variables:

```
$G$3:$I$12
```

This is a 2D range.  As such we need to tell INDEX() both what Row to look in as well as which Columns to look in.  For the row to look in, we used the previously discussed MATCH() function.  Since we want all columns and not just a specific column we use the value of 0.  If Match returns an error, or if a number greater than the number of rows or columns selected is supplied, INDEX() will return an error.  Based on the information discussed, the index function would look like:

```
=INDEX($G$3:$I$12,MATCH($B21&$A21&$C21,$A$3:$A$12,0),0)
```

You can try entering the above in a cell but it will give you an error.  if you select three adjacent cells in the same row and use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when entering the formula, Excel will add {} around the formula and it will be an array formula and should show you the three variables being used.

The same process as described above can be used for determining the second range of variable from Table 2.  The only difference here is that the forecast model number was not in a column of its own but instead in the header row surrounded by text.  As such the MID() function needed to be used to go into the header row, bypass the surrounding text and pull the model number out so it could be used as part of the CONCATENATION() used for the "what to look for" in MATCH():

```
=MID(E$20,16,1)
```

The MID() function work again with three arguments:

```
MID(Text to look in, which character to start at, how many characters to pull)
```

So in this case we are looking at the header in E20. Note the lock $ on the row number so the formula is always looking in row 20 no matter how far down it gets copied.  It is then going to the 16th character.  In this case the character "1" and pulling 1 character.  If the header had just been 1 and 2, there would be no need for the MID function and the cell (with proper lock) could have been used.

Comment: Thank you forward ed, I am going to try this and will get back to you as soon as I understand it.

Comment: @ShyamRaman Hopefully the update will give you some ideas what the formula is doing.

Comment: Just faved this for reference later. Great write up!

Comment: OMG! That was awesome, Thank you so much! i managed to not only understand this but was able to transfer this on to my file which references over 500 variables over 6+ sheets. THANK YOU SO MUCH. GOD BLESS YOU :) :) :)